# Appending query parameter to end of url with pushState

Tags: javascript, pushstate, window.location

I have a page which allows me to filter posts by a "filter" tag. I need to add any filter clicked as a query parameter. For example, the url looks like this: domain.com/category/filtered.

When the user clicks one of the filters, I currently have the page adding the filter onto the end with the appropriate structure of: `domain.com/category/filtered?filter=goods` by using the pushState() function and first checking that the `?filter=` is not already available by doing:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("=") > -1) {
    window.history.pushState({}, window.location, "?filter=" + item.slug);
}
```

However, I need to be able to append additional filters onto the end, so that the url would be similar to `domain.com/category/filtered?filter=goods&services`

I'm trying to do this by pushing the additional parameter onto the url:

```
else {
window.history.pushState({}, window.location, "&" + item.slug);
}
```

but this is not effective.

How can I append additional parameters to the end of the current url, so that each successive filter is added like so: `&services&etc`

Answer (score 0):

Store items in an Array like `const filters = ['services', 'goods', 'etc']`. You can add to it using push method `filters.push('something')` and than use `"?filter=" + fiters.join('&')`. When you want to clear the Array you can use `filters.length = 0`.

Comment: `const filters = ['services', 'goods', 'etc']; 
window.history.pushState({}, window.location, "?filter=" + filters.join('&'));`